# How to get start for video streaming

Tags: android, video, stream

I have never worked on video related project, however we have to now.

### 1. **What we tried to do**

- Build an Andriod application which can take the real time steam of video an audio.
- Send the captured stream to Server
- Other clients(Either Android client or iOS or HTML5) can view these streams
- All of the above three steps should work at the same time.
- Video streamed to server should be cached by future play.

### 2. **What I know at the moment**

I have searched at google and sf to see if someone have the same requirement.

After that I know a little about the video transformation:

**Protocol:**

```
RTSP/RTP/RTCP
  RTSP: control the state of the transformation like PLAY,PAUSE,STOP..
  RTP:  which do the real transport job
  RTCP:  work in conjunction with RTP(synchronize the stream)

HTTP:
    1) Download the small pieces of the video file and play them, use the `range-requset` to control the download(play) location.
    2) HLS by Apple. Even it said it is live stream, it is based on `.m3u8` file, by updating the index of which to do the live job.

RTMP by Adobe.
```

**Encoding:**
    Nothing I know yet.

And it seems that `RTSP/RTP/RTCP` can be used for both uploading to server and playing at the client. So it apply for the application which need high real-timing. However since the `RTSP/RTP/RTCP` based on `TCP/UDP` so getting through the Router would be a problem.

While the HTTP can only be used for playing at the client(Technologically you can stream the small pieces of file by HTTP, but I think it is not a good idea), so it can be use to play the existed video stream either from file or something else. And you don't worry about the Router, which means it can be used under complex network environment.

For our application, since we do not have a strict requirement for the real-timing during the playing. So we tried to stream the video source from the Android client to Server by `RTSP/RTP/RTCP`, and serve these streams by HTTP.

### 2. **Questions:**

- Anything wrong in all of the above?
- Is it posssible of my idea:streaming by `RTSP/RTP/RTCP` and serving
  by `HTTP`.

If yes, it seems that the Server shoud do something to cache the video to a proper format for further serving. I am not sure if this job can be done by a Video Server out of the box, or by myself?

- What should I know more about the streaming development(at least for
  my current project)? Any tutorial are welcome.

Comment: I previously worked at a company that did realtime sports videos. From that experience, I can tell you that what you're seeking to accomplish is not trivial. Our company paid vendors like Brightcove and Ooyala BUCKETs of money and we still had major challenges in this area. If you only care about Android 4.0 and above, HLS is probably your best bet. If you need to support a wider range of devices, there aren't many options that work well, everywhere and thereby every vendor solution we used came with a large NDK component. So use HLS, if you can. Otherwise prepare to write a lot of C code.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me, I do not need to know how to implement a Streaming Searver, that's  a hard job. While I can use the product like Wowza Server. I just want to know more about the things related to process of the Streaming.

Comment: Agreed. I just re-read your post a few times and I'm still not exactly clear on what you're asking. There seems to be quite a few questions embedded in your post. So it may be worthwhile to rephrase your specific problems more succinctly. Is your idea possible? Yes. Is it prudent? I think that requires more details to know for sure.